# Javadoc not found for this item

Tags: java, swing

when i am trying to add event keyevent.vk_t on my menu item its showing a compile time error..."Javadoc not found for this event"

```
jmi21 = new JMenuItem("Undo        Ctrl+Z"); //menu item 
        jmi22 = new JMenuItem("Cut         Ctrl+X"); //menu item
        jmi22.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);  //error lies here..it does not allow me to add this key event
        jmi23 = new JMenuItem("Copy        Ctrl+C");
        jmi24 = new JMenuItem("Paste       Ctrl+V");
```

Kindly help

Comment: Just a wild guess, check if you have imported `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` or any other `KeyEvent` class... Because even javafx has a KeyEvent class I guess...

Comment: What is the error log/stack trace can you post it

Comment: Adding accelerator text in the text for a JMenuItem does not make that an accelerator. Omit the accelerator part of the string and use item.setAccelerator(); it will automatically add the appropriate text to the button.